# Copy SQL Server record to Access local table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

SQL Server data will be queried by ADO recordset. Currently, I use a loop to move server data to Access local table for further process.

How to eliminate the Do-Loop? Local table has exactly same columns as the server table while local table have more columns than server which will not be filled up data by the loop.

```
Dim rsServer As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rsLocal As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim fField As ADODB.field


str = "SELECT * FROM tableServer WHERE ....."
rsServer.Open str, dbServer, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

str = "SELECT * FROM tableLocal"
rsLocal.Open str, dbLocal, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText


Do Until rsServer.EOF
    rsLocal.AddNew

    For Each fField In rsServer.Fields
        rsLocal.Fields(fField.Name).Value = rsServer.Fields(fField.Name).Value
    Next

    rsLocal.Update
    rsServer.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: insert into .......

Comment: Yes, I use INSERT when both tables are on Access local table.  Do not know how to use INSERT when source is in SQL Server while destination is in Access local table.

Comment: see @ove's answer below

Comment: As my comment to @Ove's reply, I cannot link to SQL Server.  I need to use recordset or other solution which need your comments.

Comment: why can't you link? it's essentially no different to using ADO. you can even set up a temp link programatically

Comment: I use Access Ribbon External Data command to setup link table with my backend table.  I do not have experience to setup temp link to SQL Server grammatically.  Could you give me some light?

Answer (score 1):

If you connect the SQL Server table as a remote table then Access will not differentiate between that an a local table. So you will be able to run a insert query on the local table with data from the remote table.

Comment: SQL server is not linked as remote tables.  I need to use ADO to open read only recordset.

Comment: I still don't get why you can not link the table. If you are free to do what you want with the Access database, creating a linked table manually is the easiest way.

If you still need to do it programatically, this may lead you on the right track: http://from-dao-to-ado.blogspot.no/